# Resetting Arduino via code

Tags: arduino

I have looked at a dozen different ways to reset my arduino, from connecting pins to the reset pin and jury rigging weird bits of code.
None of them work.

The one bit of code that everybody seems to be using is

```
void software_Reset() // Restarts program from beginning but does not reset the peripherals and registers
{
asm volatile ("  jmp 0");  
}
```

To which my arduino responds with

> C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGUYdTQ.s:2259: Error: bad
>   instruction `jmp 0'

And it then fails uploading the code. I don't know what to do. My full code can be found here http://pastebin.com/CA2Ms2hB but it's huge and I'm not sure if it will be of help.

If anyone could help me understand why software_Reset(); I would really appreciate it, I'm at the end of my rope here.

(also if you have other methods to reset arduino I'll gladly try them)

Comment: Nowadays an `arduino` is not automatically an UNO or at least an atmega 8 bit controller. For those it's debatable if  `jmp 0` is really worse than abusing the watchdog, but both methods should work

Comment: Is it possible you have some non-printable character before the `jmp`?  I know squat about the arduino, but (I've heard) some assemblers are fussy about which column instructions need to start in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a custom reset() function in C for AVR-Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802221/how-to-write-a-custom-reset-function-in-c-for-avr-studio)

Comment: You must read the documentation available to see what 1) assembly language instruction or 2) other macro is available to do that.  Each controller differs.  If there is one, use it. If there isn't one, you cannot do it.  Every Atmel controller I've ever used has a companion document which outlines the specific assembly instructions it supports.

Answer (score 0):

On ARM based microcontrollers you can call `NVIC_SystemReset()`.

All ARM based microcontrollers are required to implement that.

This is useful because `resetFunc()` at address 0 may not work on newer ARM based microcontrollers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to write assembly code in your arduino code editor.
Let me tell you one thing. Arduino code editor does not support assembly language code by default. You can write assembly language code in arduino code editor by going through the process mentioned below:

**Caution:** We will be modifying the arduino source code to do that.

1. Get the source code for Arduino IDE: https://github.com/arduino/arduino
2. Extract the downloaded zip file, you will get a folder named Arduino-master
3. Open the Sketch.java file in a text editor of your choice. The location of sketch.java is : Arduino-master/app/src/processing/app/Sketch.java
4. Insert the .s capability:

   a. Search for: sc.isExtension("c");

   you will see something like this:

   ```
   //3. then loop over the code[] and save each .java file

   for (SketchCode sc : code){
       if(sc.isExtension("c") || sc.isExtension("cpp") || sc.isExtension("h")){
           //no pre-processing services necessary for java files
   ```

   b. Add sc.isExtension("s") at the end of the if condition. Now your code should look like below:

   ```
   //3. then loop over the code[] and save each .java file

   for (SketchCode sc : code){
       if(sc.isExtension("c") || sc.isExtension("cpp") || sc.isExtension("h") || sc.isExtension("s")){
           //no pre-processing services necessary for java files
   ```
5. Search for: String[] getExtensions()

   You will see some code like this:

   ```
   /**
     * Returns a String[] array of proper extensions.
     */
   public String[] getExtensions() {
       return new String[] { "ino", "pde", "c", "cpp", "h" };
   }
   ```

   Insert "s" in the returned Array. So, now your code should look like this:

   ```
   /**
     * Returns a String[] array of proper extensions.
     */
   public String[] getExtensions() {
       return new String[] { "ino", "pde", "c", "cpp", "h", "s" };
   }
   ```
6. Save Sketch.java
7. Open Compiler.java in text editor of your choice. The location of Compiler.java is: Arduino-master/app/src/processing/app/debug/Compiler.java
8. Search for: compileFiles(

   In the command findFilesInFolder(), replace the capital `S` with a lowercase `s`.
9. Repeat step 8 : 3 times more... (4 tiems in total)
10. Save the Compiler.java file
11. Download the latest version of java SE 8u111 from http://www.oracle.com
12. Download and install any java command line tool. But I would recommend Apache ANT.

    If you are a windows user:

    - You can download it here: http://ant.apache.org/
    - More help on download and install on windows: https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/

    If you are a Mac user:

    - You need to install it using Homwbrew:
    - To install Homebrew:

      ```
      ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
      ```
    - And then to install Apache ANT:

      ```
      brew install ant
      ```
13. In Command line go to the directory for `Arduino-master/build`
14. Build the Arduino IDE using : `ant build`, which should end with Build Successful message.
15. Package the Arduino IDE using: `ant dist`

    It will ask you to enter a version number and give a suggestion e.g.[0105]. Just enter the suggested number with dots and asm. For example: If suggestion is [0105] then enter: `1.0.5.asm`

    This command may take 6 - 10 minutes to finish. (depending on the speed of your computer)

    Then you must get Build Successful!!!
16. The Arduino IDE that supports assembly language programming can be found in the newly created .zip file
17. Unzip the file and install the Arduino IDE application.

Now, you should be able to write assembly programs without getting errors in the Arduino IDE.

If you have any problems, Please feel free to ask.