# AVR/Arduino how to jump to address 0x0000 ("soft reset")

Tags: arduino

I have a program for Arduino written in C. There are dozens of global variables initialized inline, e.g.:

```
unsigned char wpm = 25;
unsigned char weighting = 50 ;
```

I could call `setup()` to re-initialize some features and ports, but this would leave global variables as-is. Also, ISR vectors would be left unchanged. What I want is in fact restart the processor, but without entering the bootloader, because when this happens, there already is a link established on serial port of the connected PC. I do not want to kill extra program space to write a special "reset defaults" routine, so a "software reset" sounds like a possible solution.

Is there a way to jump to 0x0000, and would it actually help much?

Thank you
Jindra

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a custom reset() function in C for AVR-Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802221/how-to-write-a-custom-reset-function-in-c-for-avr-studio)

Comment: Yes, I went through it and apparently there isn't a better option. After all, yes, reset should reset all the hardware, so it should be somehow linked to a hardware feature.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
void soft_reset() {
  void (*reboot)() = 0x0000 ;
  (*reboot)();
}
```

After calling `soft_reset()` the following will happen:

1. Program will start from scratch, i.e. `setup()` function will be run again.
2. All global variables declared with initializers will be reinitialized.

Which is exactly what I wanted.

WDT reset, the only alternative I found in the internet, seems to be rather complicated and requires some extra timeout before the reset occurs. This is faster and cleaner.